# SP2010 - Image links are pointing local URLS

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping, url, domain, image

Migrated a site from MOSS2007, and was given a new site URL of http://:/

e.g. http://spserver:1234

I have added an alternate access mapping so it can be accessed over the internet.  However none of the images show up because looking at the source its still using local server's URL.

I tried making the internet domain name the default zone and also tried Extranet but still using the local URLs.

How do I change them? It can't be hardcoded because it did pick up the new site url after migration.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve it.  I removed all other mappings, including the original local server URL.  I would have expected SharePoint to work this out intelligently though.